# Jquery Selectors in Depth

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery, jquery-filter

I am displaying name of groups from database in `ul >li` and it's parameters in `<div>` which is initially hidden. Now using jQuery I want to toggle only `<div>` but same time want to hide all others.

I have tried the following code but it does not work in jQuery 1.7. Can any one please help me how to use `.not` or `.filter` while selecting all divs that starts with "group" or some other solution?

```
$("#popupContact").delegate("ul.horizontal_lists li a", "click", function() {
    var target_id = $(this).attr('id');
    target_id = "divOf" + target_id;
    $('#' + target_id).slideToggle("slow");
    $('[id^="divOf"]'.not(this)).hide();
}
```

Comment: If possible, please make a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of your main problems is that your searching for div's, but excepting `this`.  Since `this` is an anchor, I don't think this'll ever work

```
$('[id^="divOf"]'.not(this)).hide();
```

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
var target_id = $(this).attr('id');
target_id = "divOf" + target_id;
$('#' + target_id).slideToggle("slow");
$('div[id^="divOf"]:not("#' + target_id + '")').hide();
```

The last line selects all divs that have an id starting with `divOf`, but not the one with an id of `target_id`, and hiding them

Answer (score 0):

you should also start using `on` since `delegate` has been `deprecated` in jquery 1.7.

```
$("#popupContact").on("click", "ul.horizontal_lists li a", function() {
    var target_id = $(this).attr('id');
    target_elem = $("#divOf" + target_id);
    $('[id^="divOf"]').not(target_elem).hide();
    target_elem.slideToggle("slow");
}
```

Comment: Note that the parameters for `.on()` are not in the same order as for `.delegate()` (the event(s) parameter comes first).